# Is providing digital signage for a restuarant which sells alcohol, bacon, etc., haram?

Tags: halal-haram, business

I have a question regarding digital signage. I have a Company which provides digital signage solution to customers. I provide them with complete software and hardware solutions.

I have one customer who is willing to buy my package for his restaurant which sells pizza and subs for lunch etc. He also sells beer, but this place is not a pub; it's a restaurant in a center. The customer is non-Muslim. I will also sell him templates which will present his menu on the displays. In the menu he will also obviously mention things like bacon pizza etc.

Is that kind of business haram for me?

Remember that I am only selling the hardware and software solution to him, so it does not matter for me what he sells, because I don't get any profit for that, I just sell my system.

Comment: Please wait for more answers, you are selling for a cause that assists in the process of delivering haram, if was a cutlery dealer and a customer asks whats a good knife to stab people then i will not sell him any thing, helping someone do haram is haram